# Proof that rational polynomials have at least one rational root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Every odd degree polynomial with real coefficient has at least one real root, that i can prove. but i dont know how to prove that every odd degree polynomial with rational coefficients has at least one rational root?

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you can't prove it, because, as M10687.  says, this simply **isn't true**!

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is not true over the rational numbers, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586543/why-is-the-rational-number-system-inadequate-for-analysis). So the proof you know will not work. For good reason, because it is no longer true.

Comment: You may be confused about what the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem says, which is "**if** a polynomial has a rational root, then it satisfies a certain condition" - but it doesn't say **all** polynomials **must** have rational roots.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for the proof of a non-result.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider $x^3+ 2$. Does this have a rational root?

Comment: but how do i prove it with a polynomial with rational coefficients like 3/4x^3 +2?

Comment: That polynomial has rational coefficients, 1 and 2 are rational

Comment: now i get it thank you!